# Omit optional parameters set as null in Kotlin data class

Tags: kotlin, optional-parameters, data-class

Best practice to omit optional parameter in a  data class when its assigned null?

Example: `data class xyz(val a:String ?,val b: String?, val c: String?= null)` 
if c = null, then data class xyz(val a:String ?,val b: String?).

Calling  xyz.toString()  which takes null as "null". So output is xyz("String for a", String for b", "null").

But actual output xyz("String for a", String for b").

Can I use secondary constructor or invoke() ? Which is better?

Comment: It's not entirely clear for me what you mean. Omit optional parameters when doing what exactly? When creating an object, when printing it in `toString()`? If the latter, how would you like to distinguish cases when `c`is null and `b` is null (assuming it is optional as well)? Both these cases would produce exactly same output. You can always implement `toString()` by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If you sometimes need a value c but not in this case, then the two options are:

```
val newXyzObject = xyz(a = "String for a", b = "String for b", c = null)
```

or

```
val newXyzObject = xyz(a = "String for a", b = "String for b")
```

but since c has a default value it is preferred to go with the second option because it is more readable.